# python- Increase speed looping through dataframe in calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with approximately 20000 lines, and three columns (the first column is an identifier, and other two are data corresponding with that identifier). I need to loop through the csv and solve an equation for each identifier, using their corresponding data values. Example:

- Name/variable x/variable y
- John/65/34
- Amy/23/87

For the purposes of demonstration, the equation is something like z = y * x + y/x.

It then writes to another dataframe the result.

However, it takes a super long time to complete the loop, with a loop time of about .17 seconds per loop. It's painful.

How can I optimize speed? I have heard about vectorization but do not understand it.

Example code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('thedata.csv', dtype="float")
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   x = row.x
   y = row.y
#calculate result
   z = x * y + y/x

  df['result']= z
  df.to_csv('results.csv', mode = 'a')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer, you don't iterate: `df['result'] = df['x'] * df['y'] + df['y']/df['x']`

Comment: This made it instantaneous- thank you! Excellent excellent tip.